# Insert form value into Wordpress database table :php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to insert data into Wordpress database by creating a table "wp_ecoles_details". I have created the table but when I try to insert the data from form, it does not insert the data. I have checked that database connection works, but the insertion does not happen. Can someone help me on this? Here is my code:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: cours_page
 *
 * Creates a page with posts, akin to the default index.php. Using this template you can create as many pages of posts as you want.
 *
 * @package thim
 */
get_header();



if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;   

    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    //echo ($user);
    $post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM $wpdb->pmpro_membership_orders");

    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $nom_ecole = $_POST["nom_ecole"];
    $adresse = $_POST["adresse"];     
    $postale = $_POST["postale"];
    $ville = $_POST["ville"];
    $telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
    $classes = $_POST["classes"];
    $total_eleve = $_POST["total_eleve"];
    $n_scolaire = $_POST["n_scolaire"];

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert('wp_ecoles_details', array(
                'type' =>   $type ,
                'nom_ecole' => $nom_ecole,
                'adresse' => $adresse,     
                'postale' => $postale,
                'ville' => $ville,
                'telephone' => $telephone,
                'classes' => $classes,
                'total_eleve' => $total_eleve,
                'n_scolaire' => $n_scolaire
            ),
            array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' ));

    }

?>  
        <div class="ecole_div" id="ecole_div">
            <form  method="post">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Information sur l’école:</legend>

                 <input type="radio" name="type" value="privee"> Privée
              <input type="radio" name="type" value="publique"> Publique
                <br> <br>
                Nom de l’école:<br>
                <input type="text" name="nom_ecole" value="">
                <br>
                Adresse:<br>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="adresse"  value="">
                    </textarea>
                <br> 

                Code postal:<br>
                <input type="number" name="postal" value="">
                <br>
                Ville:<br>
                <input type="text" name="ville" value="">
                <br><br>
                Téléphone école:<br>
                <input type="text" name="telephone" value="">
                <br>
                Nombre de classes:<br>
                <input type="number" name="classes" value="">
                <br><br>
                Nombre total d’élèves:<br>
                <input type="number" name="total_eleve" value="">
                <br>
                Niveau scolaire
                 <input type="checkbox" name="n_scolaire" value="maternelle"> Maternelle
              <input type="checkbox" name="n_scolaire" value="primaire"> Primaire
              <input type="checkbox" name="n_scolaire" value="elementaire"> Elémentaire
              <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
              </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: You very much need to debug your insert query ... `$wpdb->last_error; $wpdb->last_query;`

Comment: how i can use??

Comment: Insert the following right after your `$wpdb->get_results` line:

    `$wpdb->last_error;
    $wpdb->last_query;`

and post the results ...

Comment: Also after your insert statement `$wpdb->insert(...)`

Comment: Does the data needs to be in a special table? Can you provide more details about what you want to accomplish I am inferring you are trying to store some kind of address.

Comment: Turning on debug in your **wp_config.php file** can be your friend: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: Insert the following code: `$wpdb->last_error; $wpdb->last_query;`  right before your ending php tag `?>`  and let us know what it says when you refresh.

Comment: nothing change, when i click submit my page reload and as if I did not do anything

Comment: @Ahmed Trios  See last comment

Comment: i do this and the same thing

Comment: Replace last code with: `$wpdb->last_error; $wpdb->last_query; exit();` Right before endiing tag `?>`

Comment: yes ,i do this and the same thing

Comment: Modify the line `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );` to `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your **wp_config.php** file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180063/discussion-between-jamie-d-and-ahmed-trios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a field named `postal` in your form, but in your code you are trying to get value from `postale`.

Replace

```
<input type="number" name="postal" value="">
```

with th

```
<input type="number" name="postale" value="">
```

**UPDATE**:

add name attribute to the the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: i change it and and the same thing

Comment: i don't know why i don't get anythning no error and no result

Comment: Have you tried to debug as suggested by @Jamie_D ? In the config file add `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` after `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: yes the problem is i don't get any thing in post like i reload my page with nothing in post

Comment: Make sure you have  `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in your config file. After that check for debug.log file in the wp-content folder

Comment: I found one more mistake in the code of your form and updated my answer with example.

Comment: thank's a lot <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

resolve my problem